# Listening to music that inspires the story

Tags: brainstorming

Is it suggested somewhere that an author listens to a certain type of music to help with their writing process?

I'm listening to piano covers of songs I like and I found that while listening to the original while brainstorming and then coming back to listen to the piano version I remembered my brainstorming sessions....

Is this advised or should I really get a therapist?

Comment: well unfortunately, this is a bit opinion based.  Some people prefer music, some tv, others strict silence.  Personally when I am writing or doing programming, I listen to either house/trance electronic music, OR I put on piano/classical/orchestra music.  Depends on my mood but it is one of those.  No one can tell you if you need a therapist.  Usually that is reserved for deep issues of the mind that may or may  not be related to your ability to write (though it could).  If music works for you then try it, if watching anime works while you write, then try it.

Comment: Aw hell, that doesn't help. I was really wondering if it was like a memorizing technique.

Comment: The Hasidic/jewish community bob their heads up and down while they read their holy scriptures as a key for memorizing.  I don't see how it works but hey, what ever works for them.  That is exactly my point though, what works for YOU won't work for me.  There will be others where your quirks match other people's, but ultimately you know yourself.  You know if you can have the radio blasting or softly in the background.  If you need piano music or hardcore metal.  Also you don't memorize a story... you create it and bring it to life.  You can't memorize what's not on paper yet.

Comment: However, in terms of music, studies have proved that listening to complex music (progressive rock, orchestra, symphony, classical, complex electronic music), helps bring out your creative thinking.  The complexity helps you to think more and helps your mind to be focused.  Other than that man it's all personal choice.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I get it now.

Comment: If, as one of your comment suggests, you are interested in memorzing techniques, then this question if off topic on this site and might better fit CogSci.SE or Personal Productivity.

Comment: @what It's not a memorizing technique, I was wondering if it was suggested I do it.